# Varnish Cache Page while images are not

Tags: magento-2.1

We have installed Varninsh for magento 2.1.7. We want to get the images from original directory rather than being cached. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, this is possible.

You just need to edit your vcl file, to return pipe for images.

Open the file,

search

```
sub vcl_recv {
```

an add something like

```
if (req.url ~ "(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|tiff|bmp)$") {
    return (pipe);
}
```

afterwards reload varnish

Comment: what would happen if we add an nginx instance before this varnish? Would that work same like varnish piping?

Comment: adding nginx before varnish doesn't change how varnish treats the images.

Comment: Thanks Jonas. We are concerned about saving up of the storage taken up by the images folder when both the nginx and the varnish both are active.

Comment: do you add nginx as extra caching layer or is it for ssl termination?

Comment: ssl is now doing the termination now only, no extra cache layer. But if we add multiple varnish instances in a cluster arrangement, then what we should do.

Comment: well, you can either pipe everything to varnish or serve the images directly from nginx. But as this has nothing to do with this question, please start a new question about this.